# Powershell don't continue until certain key pressed

Tags: powershell

I have a script that's waiting for user input then depending on what they press does something. But, the problem is the script continues no matter what they press (but if it's not one of the two keys it's expecting, I just get errors). Here's the snippint I'm working on

```
Write-Host "What do you want to do next?" -nonewline
Write-Host "

    u - Search for another user
    c - Enter a computer name

"

# Prompt for an action
Write-Host ">> Select shortcut action: " -nonewline

$key = [Console]::ReadKey()
$value = $key.KeyChar

switch($value) {
    c { $c = Read-Host "Enter computer or IP"}
    u { $u = Read-Host "Enter user" }
}


# now we continue on with the code depending on what was pressed
```

What I'd like is if anything beyond `c` or `u` are pressed tell the user that's not a valid key and go back to the top of this snippint and prompt the user again for what action to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your code in a `do-while` loop that continues as long as `$value` is not `c` or `u`:

```
do 
{
    $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
    $value = $key.KeyChar

    switch($value) {
        c { $c = Read-Host "Enter computer or IP"}
        u { $u = Read-Host "Enter user" }
    }
}
while ($value -notmatch 'c|u')
```